# is it good to use try catch in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, try-catch

i just want to know is it good to use try catch in nodejs. for example i am using crypto modules of node js, for encryption & decryption. so i am handling any error while encryption/ decryption in try catch is it a good practice ?????

Comment: As node.js has the same architecture as Javascript, in fact implementing Javascript I don't see any drawbacks to use try catch.

Comment: i read somewhere m not getting the reference of it , that try catch is synchronous, & i don't want to  any synchronous . it is in domain modules which is depreciated now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your encryption/decryption calls are synchronous (depends on the library, module, function you use), try/catch is ok to use it, otherwise depending on how you've used it, it might be useless.

Try/catch is ok to catch a programming error or buggy code, for example from libraries you don't know might be buggy.

Like:

```
try {
  libraryLib.encrypt(notSureIfThisIsAValidParam);
} catch (err) {...}
```

You're not sure if the user/password are set, and you're not sure if the crypto library might fail, so you wrap it.

But try/catch also creates a new execution context, copies over scopes and all, and this is a costly operation, in terms of CPU time. It means that you should try to avoid try/catch in hot code paths.

Logic/business errors in Node are usually handled with error-first callback patterns (or Promises, or similar). Generally you'd only use try/catch if you expect programmer errors (ie. bugs), and other patterns for errors you *expect*.

Of course, this is just one line of reasoning, and I generally see a lot of intentional `throw` clauses (meant to use with try/catc) in Node code written by Java converts. But that might be specific to me, so YMMV.

Comment: yes for that purpose i don't want to use try catch, promises is a good option, but it have error & catch function to handle error, so does promise modules internally uses try catch for error handling.

Comment: No, Promises don't use try/catch per se. You can think of promises as a decoupled callback function in a way: instead of `getUser(name, function(err, content) { /* here you have one callback with both error and content */ });` you would use `getUserPromise(name).then(function contentCB(content){}, function errorCB(err) {});`
Of course, it's not as simple as that, but that's the gist of it in this context. (And of course, async flow flattening, error handling on one place etc etc etc out of scope of _this_ question.)